# Is there a way to artificially slow down Apache http server transactions to simulate load?

Tags: apache-httpd, performance, testing

Is there a way to artificially slow down Apache http server transactions to simulate load?

I'd need to force http transactions to take 100ms+ instead of the normal 3ms, without killing the CPU or otherwise affecting other processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
tc qdisc add dev <intf> root netem delay 100ms
```

**More details**

NetEm (Wetwork Emulator) is a TC based tool which allows you to introduce all sorts of behaviours to your transmission, such as delay, errors, drops and more. See [this tutorial](https://netbeez.net/blog/how-to-use-the-linux-traffic-control/) for more instructions.

In order to add delay to all outgoing packets you can use this command:

```
tc qdisc add dev <intf> root netem delay <delay in ms>ms
```

**Example**

Without delay:

```
$ping 11.141.69.20
PING 11.141.69.20 (11.141.69.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 11.141.69.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 11.141.69.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
```

Adding 200ms delay:

```
$tc qdisc add dev ens4f0 root netem delay 200ms
```

And now:

```
$ping 11.141.69.20
PING 11.141.69.20 (11.141.69.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 11.141.69.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=200 ms
64 bytes from 11.141.69.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=200 ms
```

You can view the rules for a device like so:

```
$tc qdisc show dev ens4f0
qdisc netem 8001: root refcnt 161 limit 1000 delay 200.0ms
```

And revert a rule by deleting it:

```
$tc qdisc del dev ens4f0 root netem delay 200ms
```

After deleting latency is restored:

```
$ping 11.141.69.20
PING 11.141.69.20 (11.141.69.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 11.141.69.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.114 ms
64 bytes from 11.141.69.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that the OP wants to simulate a http server faltering under load, not a slow/flaky network

Comment: "I'd need to force http transactions to take 100ms+ instead of the normal 3ms" - this would achieve that.

Comment: Very useful to me too. Thanks Tgilgul